# Codeigniter Curl Library Response

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I am working on a Codeigniter project where I make a server call to another project on another server. On the second project, the server call request can encounter a success or failure, but for either case, am setting custom messages indicating the result(Success or Failed).

Now back to the first project, I make the server call to second project using the Codeigniter Curl library by Phil Sturgeon. When the server call is a success(200) I get the desired sucess custom message, while when it fails all I get is a FALSE. The failure custom message gets dropped. Is there any way to get the custom message even when it fails.?

Comment: Define fail. Is the failure here the inability of the first project to connect with the second query, or is it a non-200 response?

Comment: It is a non 200 response.. like for login something like invalid password or email.